# Не устанавливается Avalonia UI на Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

Установил .NET Core SDK 2.2.300, пытаюсь установить AvaloniaUI через меню Tools -> Extensions and Updates:

[image: Avalonia for Visual Studio]

Она скачивается, вылезает текст, приглашающий закрыть студию:

[image: Avalonia скачалась]

Закрываю студию, запускается установщик, но он отрабатывает с ошибкой:

[image: Ошибка]

Лог установки [здесь](https://pastebin.com/bdfJA9yn).

Не могу понять, что ему не нравится.

Comment: Читаем внимательно лог. По русски написано что несоответствие версий " Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools". Та что установлена у вас не подходит под требования расширения.

Comment: @NikolajSarry Это я вижу, но я не понимаю, какая версия соответствует описанию "Version      : [15.8.27729.1,17.0)". Я установил последнюю стабильную версию.

Comment: @NikolajSarry На русском SO нет тэга avaloniaui. Добавите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что требуется обновить саму Visual Studio. После обновления без проблем установилось.